# How to script XML Schema collection in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, xml, xsd

I need to make script of XML schema collections in my Database and then insert each xml inside a table field as string.

I need to do this to compare current schema collections with the new schema collections after it is regenerated.

I have no idea where to start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the Question correctly, you need to use the [XML_SCHEMA_NAMESPACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190316.aspx) built-in function to extract the Schema Collection, and you can find the list of those in the [sys.xml_schema_collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190335.aspx) system catalog view. You can use something along the lines of:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), XML_SCHEMA_NAMESPACE(sch.[name], xsc.[name])) AS [XSD]
FROM   sys.xml_schema_collections xsc
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
        ON sch.[schema_id] = xsc.[schema_id]
WHERE  xsc.[xml_collection_id] <> 1;
```

I put the `WHERE  xsc.[xml_collection_id] <> 1` filter in there to avoid getting the following error:

> Msg 6314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Collection specified does not exist in metadata : 'sys'